# Photoshop export for web and devices comes out pixelated

Tags: web, adobe, photoshop

When I export for web and devices in photoshop CS5 it comes out pixelated. What setting should I change?

I have a picture of my export settings

Comment: You should ask this question over at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/
Ohh, and please add more details: What settings do you have, what images do use, ...

Comment: Also posted here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1940/photoshop-export-for-web-and-devices-comes-out-pixelated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing `pixelation` with `posterization`.

**Pixelation** only occurs when you try and display an image larger than its native resoluion, ie: enlarging it much larger than it was originally.

**Posterization** occurs when you reduce the number of colors to a pallet with a fixed number of colors that can't accomadate all the colors in your image.

**Solution**

In your case, you are cutting the color space down from 24 bit full color to index color 8 bit, you can't get enough colors in `256` colors in your palette to represent all the colors in the 24 bit original.

I don't know why you need a 256 index color palette, that such as 1997 requirement, but if you really need to cut your full color images down to 256 colors **you need to enable `dithering`** so that it can try and create intermediate colors by mixing the palette colors and tricking the eye to see more colors than are actually there.

There are different dithering algorthims in Photoshop, try them and see which one gives you the best results.

If you don't really have a requirement for only 256 colors, then set it to 24 bit full color.

In reality you have it set to `selective` and are only actually generating a `53` color palette, that all those images have to share colors from, that will **never** look good.

Comment: I dont need that many colors but the image i'm starting off with is 3000 by 4000 px what is the best way to scale it down and cut it up without loosing its clarity?

Comment: has nothing to do with scaling and everything to do with cutting the number of colors from 24 bit down to 8 bit, which is what you are doing in your settings screen shot.

Comment: ok the images are fine now but some of the text is pixelated look at the image below I'm exporting at a png 24 http://www.brandonsdesigngroup.com/fa_website/portfolio/hampton/images/hampton_04.png

Comment: you need to anti-alias the text when flattening it into the background

Comment: but i don't flatten it should I will that alleviate this problem?

Comment: this is the first link on google for ["anti-alias photoshop"](http://www.mccannas.com/pshop/pshop3.htm)

Comment: @brandon's design group you have to flatten the image to export to anything like png or jpeg that doesn't support layers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After excessive experimenting, the solution turned out to be real simple. Do not make use of the option resize while you save to web. Use the actual size of the document in psd or move the layers to a smaller document. Note that i do use png24 for best quality.